# Script works, but only on one spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script works, for the first sheet of my [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OxoC7FFFH1AdVLiCklGWRL4R_Zv6Xm5tjc7s_URaAsY/edit?usp=sharing). But it does not work for other sheets in my workbook, even though `Logger.log(sheet.getName())` successfully fetches the name of the sheet that is currently being edited. It's a pretty simple problem, I just can't figure out why it only works for one of my sheets.

```
function onEdit (e) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
      Logger.log(sheet.getName())
      if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C19' && e.value == 'TRUE') {
        sheet.getRange('K2:K89').setNumberFormat("0.00oz")
      }
        else if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C19' && e.value == 'FALSE'){
          sheet.getRange('K2:K89').setNumberFormat("0.00g")
        }
```

Comment: Did `w2lf` reply below solve your problem? Looks like it makes sense. Actually I had not realised that when you create a checkbox it gives the options of `yes/no`,`true/false`, `1/0` etc. You have to remember what you chose when programming! I wonder if the 1/0 can be treated as a Boolean?

Comment: He did, I guess I got confused there. Thanks for helping anyway bcperth, much appreciated. I spent so long on this damn thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 'Loadout Picker' C19 values are TRUE/FALSE

In 'Copy of Loadout Picker 2.0' C19 values are 1/0

In the script in your if loops you have C19 == 'FALSE'/'TRUE'

That's the problem. Just remake a new tickbox at cell C19 in 'Copy of Loadout Picker 2.0' and it will reset the C19 values to TRUE/FALSE from 1/0. (Don't forget to rejoin the spreadsheet or just switch between the sheets so the code starts to work.)

That's also why onEdit() worked for the first sheet and not second.

Comment: Hey... how stupid of me. I spent so long on it too. I have multiple versions of this spreadsheet where I was experimenting with different ways of implementing the format column. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: np happy it helped. At first, I thought something was wrong with the code too. So I made a copy of the spreadsheet and organized a bit your custom function added the missing ; and moved the brackets a bit {} and added a few more loggers and it looked all right and then I checked the C19 values and noticed the 1/0.